# Runtime Error in Google CodeJam 2020 Vestigium

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

**Vestigium** means "trace" in Latin.

The trace of a square matrix is the sum of the values on the main diagonal (which runs from the upper left to the lower right).

An N-by-N square matrix is a Latin square if each cell contains one of N different values, and no value is repeated within a row or a column. In this problem, we will deal only with "natural Latin squares" in which the N values are the integers between 1 and N.

Given a matrix that contains only integers between 1 and N, we want to compute its trace and check whether it is a natural Latin square. To give some additional information, instead of simply telling us whether the matrix is a natural Latin square or not, please compute the number of rows and the number of columns that contain repeated values.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Solution
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
        int T,N,matrix[][],dupCheck[];
        int i,j,k,r,c,Sum;
        String inMat[];
        dupCheck=new int[100];
        T=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        for(k=1;k<=T;k++,matrix=null)
        {
            N=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            matrix=new int[N][N];
            for(i=0,r=0;i<N;i++)
            {
                inMat=(sc.nextLine()).split(" ");
                Arrays.fill(dupCheck,0);
                for(j=0;j<N;j++)
                {
                    matrix[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(inMat[j]);
                    dupCheck[matrix[i][j]]++;
                }
                for(j=0;j<100;j++)
                {
                    if(dupCheck[j]>1)
                    {
                        r++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            for(i=0,Sum=0;i<N;i++) Sum+=matrix[i][i];

            for(i=0,c=0;i<N;i++)
            {
                Arrays.fill(dupCheck,0);
                for(j=0;j<N;j++)
                {
                    dupCheck[matrix[j][i]]++;
                }
                for(j=0;j<100;j++)
                {
                    if(dupCheck[j]>1)
                    {
                        c++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Case #"+k+": "+Sum+" "+r+" "+c);
        }
    }
}
```

It runs fine in IDE and also gives Correct Answer.
But I am getting a Runtime Error when I submit.

Comment: UPDATE: I commented & uncommented my entire code and found out that last inner for loop is causing the error.
What could be wrong with
```for(j=0;j<100;j++)
                {
                    if(dupCheck[j]>1)
                    {
                        c++;
                        break;
                    }
                }```

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding sc.close(); before closing main method.

Comment: Still getting Runtime Error.

Answer (score 0):

The Runtime error is coming because your code is working for the first case, then giving answer. Then when we enter another case, it also gives an answer. But by Google they will enter all cases at once and then you need to give the answers for all the cases in single-single lines.